# How to target container of a div in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, containers, hover

I created a very easy javascript line to change the image on hover, https://designordering.com/wink/ however, I would like to make this hover effect on the entire container instead just on the image that has the image and the "Say Hi" text. Which is actually working now because I added it directly on the HTML tag.

```
    <div class="sayHi" onhover="contact" onmouseover="document.getElementById('myImage').src='./img/face-wink.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('myImage').src='./img/face.png'">
        <span style="font-size:1.5rem; font-family:Roboto, sans-serif; font-weight:600; padding-right: 15px;">Say Hi</span>
        <img class="face" id="myImage" src="./img/face.png" alt="face" height="80px">
    </div>
```

However, I want to move this script to an external JS file and I have a hard time finding the solution for it.
Can you help me, please?

I am trying to target the container div instead of the image tag. Or to find a solution how can I move this to an external JS file

```
 onmouseover="document.getElementById('myImage').src='./img/face-wink.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('myImage').src='./img/face.png'"
```

Comment: what doesn't work when you "move this script to an external JS file"? How exactly are you trying to do that? Show us some code and we can tell you where you're going wrong, without that non-working code it's completely guesswork.

Comment: that is the html div. and I added this to it:

onhover="contact" onmouseover="document.getElementById('myImage').src='./img/face-wink.png'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('myImage').src='./img/face.png'"

How can put this to an external javascript?

Comment: Use `addEventListener('mouseover', ...)` in the script to add the event listener. The function can use `event.target` to get the element, and `event.target.parentElement` to get its container element.

Comment: You can also put the code in a function, then use `onmouseover="functionName('myimage')"`

Comment: thank you so much @Barmar,  I will try it. So far I was trying this

`function myFunction(wink) {
    wink.src="/img/face-wink.png";
    }

function myOtherFunction(face) {
    face.src="/img/face.png";
    }

onmouseover="myFunction(this)"; onmouseout="myOtherFunction(this)";`

however, I can not put this on the parent container.

Comment: You want mouseenter and mouseleave. So what is the issue? Have you not used addEventListener before?

Comment: works with mouseover and mouseout as well, the only issue is that I can not target the parent container if I want to put in the external JS file

Answer (score -1):

You could do this by referring to the div element in the javascript code

```js
const sayHiDiv = document.querySelector(".sayHi");
const myImage = document.getElementById("myImage");
sayHiDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", e => myImage.src = "./img/face-wink.png");
sayHiDiv.addEventListener("mouseout", e => myImage.src = "./img/face.png");
```

**Edit**

If a more modular approach is needed (if you can't access the element in the javascript) then you can define a function instead

```js
function changeImage (div, src)
{
    div.querySelector("img").src = src;
}
```

The function can then be used to simplify the HTML

```html
<div class="sayHi" onmouseover="changeImage(this, '.img/face-wink.png');" onmouseout="changeImage(this, '.img/face.png');" >
    <!-- span and img -->
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, Paul, this resolved the issue 100%!

Comment: @roko, yes I am a newbie here

Comment: You should never use `mouseover` / `out` (unless you really know what you're doing.) use `mouseenter` `mouseleave` instead. Also you should not use inline HTML `on*` attribute handlers. You should use .addEventListener() instead from your JS file or tag script.